# Why canvasjs spline chart shows 00:00 in axis x

Tags: canvasjs

I have canvasJS V3.6.7, where i want to display temperature data in a spline graph.

**Simple data set:**

```
chartTempData = [];
chartTempData.push(
    {x: new Date(2022,7,26,16,24), y: 32.3},
    {x: new Date(2022,8,7,12,21), y: 35.3},
);
```

**The chart options:**

```
chartTempOptions = {
    axisX: {
        title: "Mérés ideje",
        valueFormatString: "HH:mm DD MMM"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Celsius °C",
    },
    data: [{
        yValueFormatString: "#0.## °C",
        xValueFormatString: "HH:mm",
        type: "spline",
        xValueType: "dateTime",
        dataPoints: chartTempData
    }]
};
```

In the X Axis i can see the days, but the time part is 00:00. so, it seems `valueFormatString` is not working properly.

When I select a data point, though i can see the proper time part of the data point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis labels are rendered at every interval from a auto-calculated initial point & not for every datapoint. Please refer this [forum thread](https://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/x-axis-labels-are-not-aligned-vertical-with-the-data-points/) for more information. In your case, you can pass label property and make it a category axis instead of passing x-value. Below is the working code.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  axisX: {
    title: "Mérés ideje",
    valueFormatString: "HH:mm DD MMM"
  },
  axisY: {
    title: "Celsius °C",
  },
  data: [{
    yValueFormatString: "#0.## °C",
    xValueFormatString: "HH:mm",
    type: "spline",
    xValueType: "dateTime",
    dataPoints: [
      { label: "16:24 26 Aug", y: 32.3},
      { label: "12:21 12 Sep", y: 35.3},
    ]
  }]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunately i didn't know about that label property of dataPoints. and due to deadline constraints i selected another graph framework...